# Datetime VB net to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I have this:

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
    Try
        Dim a As String
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
        con.Open()
        Dim laser As String
        Dim debit As String
        Dim indoire As String
        Dim uzinaj As String
        Dim dlaser As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DateTime.Now
        Dim ddebit As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DateTime.Now
        Dim dindoire As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DateTime.Now
        Dim duzinaj As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DateTime.Now
        If NewCheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            laser = "Finished"
        Else
            laser = "In Progress"
            dlaser = Nothing
        End If
        If NewCheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            debit = "Finished"
        Else
            debit = "In Progress"
            ddebit = Nothing
        End If
        If NewCheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            indoire = "Finished"
        Else
            indoire = "In Progress"
            dindoire = Nothing
        End If
        If NewCheckBox4.Checked = True Then
            uzinaj = "Finished"
        Else
            uzinaj = "In Progress"
            duzinaj = Nothing
        End If
        a = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SC Vermorel SRL$PregatirePROD]
       (
        [FPO]
       ,[Articol]
       ,[Descriere]
       ,[Cantitate]
       ,[LASER]
       ,[DEBITARE]
       ,[INDOIRE]
       ,[UZINAJ]
       ,[EndDateLASER]
       ,[EndDateDEBIT]
       ,[EndDateINDOIRE]
       ,[EndDateUZINAJ])
 VALUES
       (@FPO,
        @Articol
       ,@Descriere
       ,@Cantitate
       ,@LASER
       ,@DEBITARE
       ,@INDOIRE
       ,@UZINAJ
       ,@EndDateLASER
       ,@EndDateDEBIT
       ,@EndDateINDOIRE
       ,@EndDateUZINAJ)"
        myCommand = New SqlCommand(a, con)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FPO", txtFpo.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Articol", txtItem.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descriere", txtDesc.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantitate", txtQty.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASER", laser)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEBITARE", debit)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INDOIRE", indoire)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UZINAJ", uzinaj)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateLaser", dlaser)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateDEBIT", ddebit)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateINDOIRE", dindoire)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateUZINAJ", duzinaj)
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Eroare ..." & ex.Message, "Inserare campuri")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    Me.SC_Vermorel_SRL_PregatirePRODTableAdapter.Fill(Me.NAV_Vermorel_LiveDataSet._SC_Vermorel_SRL_PregatirePROD)
End Sub
```

The table design from, prtscreen from SSM:

[image: tabledesign]

Im trying to add the DateTime.Now value of dlaser into an SQL field. I get SQL type overflow, dates must be between etc etc.

The format of date witch SMS displays is: 2016-09-30 14:58:46.343. SQL Server 2005.

How can i be sure that vb net application outputs datetime in same format?

Comment: The code that you've provided doesn't actually match what you say you're doing.  If you want help with some code that doesn't work then providing that actual code would be a good place to start.  You might also provide the actual error message, rather than some vague approximation.  Detail matters.  What is the data type of the column you're trying to insert the data into?

Comment: If you work with the correct datatype (datetime) across your .NET code and SQL Server, you don't need to care about the display format because it is only a _display_ format and not data storage. The reason you get your overflow exception is that somewhere along the flow, you do not handle it in the correct datatype but likely a string that's vulnerable to your current culture information / locale

Comment: Also, the code you have posted is using `SqlDbType.Date`, which corresponds to the SQL Server `date` data type.  That is only for dates, not times as well. The fact that you are using `DateTime.Now` and that your formatted text includes a time indicates that that is not what you should be using.  If you want to store dates and times then you should be using `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server and the corresponding `SqlDbType` in your ADO.NET code.

Comment: You are right. I always post questions in a hurry. I will do better next time. I edited my post to include all data needed for you guys to debug, if you are kind enough. Thanks again. I've put datetime where you indicated, still same error.

Comment: Don´t use `AddWithValue`. Use `Add`, e.g. `myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Laser", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dlaser`.

Comment: Now it says: TheSqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Boolean objects.

Comment: Btw.. you never add @dlaser to your parameters when checkbox is not checked. You only add it when its value is null.

Comment: But..the not checked state of checkbox is not handled by if then clause? if not checked, then add a null value in the field. right? or i'm getting in wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Else` part you leave VB variable `dlaser` uninitialized, which means it has value `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. But that variable is always used for parameter `@EndDateLaser` to set column [EndDateLASER].

Column [EndDateLASER] has SQL type `datetime`, but `datetime` does not allow `0001-01-01`, the minimum value allowed is `1753-01-01`.

Apart from that, I wonder why you *sometimes* add a `@dlaser` SqlParameter (with value DBNull). For the query as shown that parameter is irrelevant because it does not use `@dlaser` anywhere. And also, why add it only in one situation, while your query is fixed.

Comment: Thanks alot for pointing tgat out. it was total nonsense. i edited main post and i tried to assing a null value do the variable in the else part. but now it says that a parameter value is expected at debug. i give up. cannot for the love of god figure it, if a chekcbox is checked, insert date, if not, insert null...

Comment: Column [EndDateLASER] is marked as `NOT NULL`. You can insert NULL if you mark it as `NULL`. Just put a checkmark in the Allow Null column in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This

> DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

in Place of

> DateTime.Now

and dlaser is take string

> dim dlaser as string